# Modal automatico temporizado

Tags: javascript, html5, modal, timer

Como puedo hacer para lanzar un modal en forma de alerta en `JavaScript` que se active y se desactive automáticamente a determinada hora.

al activarse, Por favor algo de documentación, sugerencia o ayuda. Gracias.

Gracias de antemano a las respuestas ya recibidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas que esté activo por ejemplo entre las 10 am y las 05:59 pm puedes evaluar la hora actual y a partir de allí decidir si ocultar o mostrar un elemento:

```
var fecha = new Date();
var hora = fecha.getHours();

if (hora > 9 && hora < 18) { // Aqui puedes checkear minutos, segundos y combinar criterios lógicos
    document.getElementById("miModal").style.display = "block";
} else {
    document.getElementById("miModal").style.display = "none";
}
```

Suponiendo que tienes un elemento que tiene un id="miModal" ese elemento aparecerá entre las horas indicadas.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="miModal" style="display: block;">
      <h1>My First Heading</h1>
      <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
    var fecha = new Date();
    var hora = fecha.getHours();
    alert(hora);

        if (hora > 9 && hora < 18) { // Aqui puedes checkear minutos, segundos y combinar criterios lógicos
            document.getElementById("miModal").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("miModal").style.display = "block";
        }
    </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes apoyarte en las funciones [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) y [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), estas funciones lo que hacen es ejecutar el código que necesites cuando ha pasado por lo menos el intervalo de tiempo que indiques como parámetro.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Hola luego de 3 segundos');
}, 3000);
```

La diferencia entre estas dos funciones es que la primera se ejecuta una única vez y la otra de manera repetida cada intervalo de tiempo.

También existen otras dos funciones que son la contraparte, sirven para cancelar la ejecución de estas [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) y [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) y se usan así:

```js
var i = 0;
var intervalId = setInterval(() => { console.log(`Hola ${i++}`); }, 1000);

document.getElementById('boton')
        .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          console.log('detenido');
        });
```

```html
<button id="boton">Detener</button>
```